# How to use "match_parent" with Xamarin Forms' "VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand""?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use WebView in Xamarin Forms like this:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <local:HybridWebView x:Name="hybridWebView" Uri="https://code4nara.github.io/Maplat/?appid=jizoapp&amp;overlay=true" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

But in side of this webview, height of http body shrinks to 0, so css "**height:100%**" or so not works.
I searched about thi issue, This article is found.
[Android WebView: how to let the css use the entire height w/ position absolute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049071/android-webview-how-to-let-the-css-use-the-entire-height-w-position-absolute/39111065)
It says,

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

causes webview body's height 0px.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

works well.

So, I believe Xamarin Forms' "**VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"**" uses "**android:layout_alignParentXXX**" instead of "**android:layout_height="match_parent"**".
Is there any way to make sure to use "**android:layout_height="match_parent"**" by Xamarin.Forms?

Regards,

Kohei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Android implementation](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/WebViewRenderer.cs) (line 70 - 75) of the WebViewRenderer in Xamarin.Forms I can see that in fact **match_parent** is the default height and width when creating the native WebView Control.

Working with Xamarin.Forms anytime you need to do something very specific for a platform you can do it with CustomRenderers.

Here you can subclass the WebViewRenderer and modify to your needs.